# Why my PHP is returning NULL on AJAX call?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to return an array from PHP to AJAX but it is returning NULL instead of the data I am sending back to AJAX

Here is my code

**header.php**

```
<?php
  include_once("obtainData.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>AJAX CALL</title>

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    include_once("header.php");
?>

<div>
  <h3>AJAX CALL</h3>
  <p>
    <?php
      sendData();
    ?>
  </p>
</div>

<?php
    include_once("footer.php");
?>
```

**footer.php**

```
        <script>
            $.ajax({
              url: "obtainData.php",
              data: {action: 'sendData'},
              type: 'GET',
              success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                alert("Success");
              },
              error: function() {
                alert( "Error." );
              }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**obtainData.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["action"])){
        $action = $_POST['action'];
        switch($action) {
            case 'sendData':
                sendData();
                break;
        }
    }

    function sendData(){
        $array = [];

        for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++){
            $array[$i] = "prove";
        }

        echo json_encode($array);
    }
?>
```

If I call my `sendData` method on my embeded PHP it shows me the output but I am not able to get it from AJAX call.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: change the GET OR the POST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `type: 'GET',` in your Ajax call.

And you are trying to retrieve `$_POST` in your php file.That's why getting nothing.

SO change `type: 'GET',` to `type: 'POST',`

Comment: Well... I am so embarrassed now. Yes, it was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you're sending a GET request, but using `$_POST` to retrieve the value. As a result `isset($_POST["action"])` is always false.

Either use `$_GET` to retrieve the values in your PHP code, or change the jQuery to send a `POST` request.